# SELECT *, sum() with equation only returns one row

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *, 
       (SUM(`q6`) / 
       (`q1` * 
           (`q1` + `q2` + `q3` + `q4` + `q5` + `q6`) / 6) 
       * 100) AS percent 
FROM table 
WHERE field2 = 'xxx'
ORDER BY `percent` ASC
```

The code above is returning me the correct value for "percent" but only returns one row. I need it to return all the rows, 15 of them.

In my equation I am trying to get the value "percent" for each row and ORDER by the highest percent.

It seems, as soon as I add the `sum()` to my select statement, that it then returns only one row.

Comment: if you want to return multiple rows, you should be using `GROUP BY` in your query.

Comment: If you want "ORDER by the highest percent at the top", say "ORDER BY `percent` DESC"

Comment: As documented under [`GROUP BY` (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html): "*If you use a group function in a statement containing no `GROUP BY` clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.*"

Comment: No, `GROUP BY` is different from `ORDER BY`. `GROUP BY` aggregates row while `ORDER BY` sorts row. here's an example of using `GROUP BY` http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php

Comment: Why do you have `WHERE field2 = 'xxx'`? Do you only want to calculate percentages of those rows? How many such rows are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all comments, you should get something like:

```
SELECT 
  *, (SUM(`q6`) / (`q1` * (`q1` + `q2` + `q3` + `q4` + `q5` + `q6`) / 6) * 100) 
  AS percent 
FROM table 
WHERE field2 = 'xxx' 
GROUP BY id ORDER BY `percent` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can include columns in the `select` that are not aggregated and not in the `group by`.  Because your query has an aggregation function, MySQL recognizes it as an aggregation query, and only returns one row.

Actually, you need to bring in the total value for a calculation on each row.  Here is one way using a subquery in the `select` statement:

```
SELECT *,
       (select sum(q6) as sumq6 from table where field2 = 'xxx') / (`q1` * (`q1` + `q2` + `q3` + `q4` + `q5` + `q6`) / 6) 
* 100) AS percent
FROM table
WHERE field2 = 'xxx'
ORDER BY `percent` ASC;
```

Here is another way, using a `cross join`:

```
SELECT *,
      (sumq6 / (`q1` * (`q1` + `q2` + `q3` + `q4` + `q5` + `q6`) / 6) 
FROM table cross join
     (select sum(q6) as sumq6 from table where field2 = 'xxx') as const
WHERE field2 = 'xxx'
ORDER BY `percent` ASC;
```